# How to set protractor to show line in which the test had failed

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor, browser-automation

How can I set it up, so that when test fails, report log shows the line in which it had failed?

Example: Nightwatch terminal log would show something like this:

```
testing command1
testing command2
   Error sharedFunctions.js (5:23) // 5-line, 23-character where the error occured
         componentHelper.js (236:32) // place where sharedFunctions was called
         test.js (56:12) // place in test where componentHelper was called
```

Could it be possible to make something similar with protractor?

Answer (score 0):

Running your tests with protractor directly shows this. For example :

```
➜  MyApp git:(master) ✗ protractor conf.js 
[08:59:29] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[08:59:29] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[08:59:29] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.157.128:52662/wd/hub
Started
F
F.

Failures:
1) My tests Loads and login
  Message:
    Expected 'My variable' to equal 'Welcome!'.
  Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/MyApp/ConvertedJSFiles/mytests_1.js:65:39)
        at step (/MyApp/ConvertedJSFiles/mytests_1.js:32:23)
        at Object.next (/MyApp/ConvertedJSFiles/mytests_1.js:13:53)
        at fulfilled (/MyApp/ConvertedJSFiles/mytests_1.js:4:58)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

2) My Second Test
  Message:
    Expected 0 to be 4.
  Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/MyApp/ConvertedJSFiles/mytests_1.js:91:37)
        at step (/MyApp/ConvertedJSFiles/mytests_1.js:32:23)
        at Object.next (/MyApp/ConvertedJSFiles/mytests_1.js:13:53)
        at fulfilled (/MyApp/ConvertedJSFiles/mytests_1.js:4:58)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

3 specs, 2 failures
Finished in 5.991 seconds

[08:59:37] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[08:59:37] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[08:59:37] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 2 test(s)
[08:59:37] I/launcher - overall: 2 failed spec(s)
[08:59:37] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

---

UPDATE:

Since I'm not allowed to disclose the code, here are the relevant parts:

```
// shared-helper.ts:
export class SharedHelper {
    // ...
    public static isPresentAndVisible(el: ElementFinder, expectedResult: boolean, nameUponFail = 'Element'): void {
        el.isPresent().then(present => {
            if (present !== expectedResult) {
                // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                global.console.log('[isPresentAndVisible] ERROR: [', nameUponFail, ']\'s presence was expected to be [', expectedResult, '] and it was not');
                expect(present).toEqual(expectedResult);
            } else if (expectedResult) {
                el.isDisplayed().then(displayed => {
                    if (displayed !== expectedResult) {
                        // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                        global.console.log('[isPresentAndVisible] ERROR: [', nameUponFail, ']\'s visibility was expected to be [', expectedResult, '] and it was not. Presence was confirmed though');
                    }
                    expect(displayed).toEqual(expectedResult);
                });
            } else {
                expect(present).toEqual(expectedResult);
            }
        });
    }
    // ...
}

// m-helper.ts:

export class MHelper {
    // ...
    public static checkM(someParameters): void {
        // ...
        SharedHelper.isPresentAndVisible(someArguments);
        // ...
    }
}


// test.ts:

// ...
it('Test', () => {
    // ...
    MHelper.checkM(someArguments);
    // ...
});

//protractor.conf.js:

const {
    SpecReporter
} = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

var screenShotReporter = require('./e2e/reporter/screenshot-reporter');

exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 90000,  // original value: 11000
    getPageTimeout: 30000,  // original value: 20000
    suites: {
        ...
        regression: './e2e/src/regression/.test.ts',
        ...
    },
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            prefs: {
                'profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications': 2
            }
        }
    },
    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 50000,
        print: function () {}
    },
    onPrepare() {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
        });
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
            suite: {
                displayNumber: true
            },
            spec: {
                displayStacktrace: true,
                displayDuration: true
            }
        }));
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(screenShotReporter);

        setTimeout(function() {
            browser.driver.executeScript(function() {
                return {
                    width: window.screen.availWidth,
                    height: window.screen.availHeight
                };
            }).then(function(result) {
                browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(result.width, result.height);
            });
        });
    }
};
```

---

### RESULT:

isPresentAndVisible failed; this is log:

```
[12:10:58] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
Jasmine started
[isPresentAndVisible] ERROR: [ xBtn ]'s presence was expected to be [ true ] and it was not

  1 DescName

    1.1
      ✗ Test (17 secs)
        - Expected false to equal true.
            at /home/zzzz/zzzz/projName/zzzz/e2e/src/utils/helpers/shared.ts:478:21
            at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
            at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
            at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
            at asyncRun (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
            at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
            at <anonymous>
            at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

**************************************************
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************

1) ...Test
  - Expected false to equal true.

Executed 1 of 803 specs (1 FAILED) (802 SKIPPED) in 24 secs.
[12:11:24] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[12:11:24] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[12:11:24] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[12:11:24] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
*/
```

As you can see, here, I've received information about fail in sharedHelper, but not where isPresentAndVisible func was called (it is used multiple times).
Also, there is even less info (no file created by me is referenced in the log) when browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(btn)); is called;

Comment: Yes, but the problem I have with this is that, almost always, these xx:xx show it(..) in which a line had failed and not the line itself

Comment: Please share your conf.js and possibly a code snippet to reproduce. I assume you do use jasmine framework, as per the tag set in your question.

Comment: I've added them in the issue description